# Cordova not building app

Tags: android, windows, cordova, android-studio

I am new to cordova. Trying to work out with it but when I check requirements it says Android Target not installed while I have installed SDK in Android Studio. 
Required information for troubleshooting can be found [here](https://www.pastebin.com/ALd4Bizw).

I am using Windows 8.1 32 bit installation. I have already tried previous answers found oh the site.

#### Update

I just noticed that running `cordova build android` gives

```
D:\Android\Apps\hell>cordova platform ls
Installed platforms:
  android 7.0.0
Available platforms:
  browser ~5.0.1
  ios ~4.5.4
  osx ~4.0.1
  windows ~5.0.0
  www ^3.12.0
```

Indicating android version to be 7.0.0 thus API is 24.
But `D:\Android\Apps\hell\platforms\android\CordovaLib\project.properties` have :

```
# Indicates whether an apk should be generated for each density.
split.density=false
# Project target.
target=android-26
apk-configurations=
renderscript.opt.level=O0
android.library=true
```

Here target is set to android-26, which is Android 8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell the path setting for the SDK is missing. Check the Cordova documentation for that. Follow it to the letter.

Also Android 7.0.0 is not the version of Android, but of the Cordova code for Android.

Josem might be onto something as well, unless you've already done that step.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the platform *android* is not installed.
Can you see it?

```
ionic cordova platform list
```

If it is not there, you can add it:

```
ionic cordova platform add android
```

Here is the [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/cordova/platform/).

Comment: `iconic` is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Comment: `cordova platform ls` gives `android@7.0.0` as installed platforms